# Azure's Mobile App Service URL response

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

Azure gives a URL of the `App Service` when an App Service is created in it. I use a `URL Ping test` (a feature provided by App Insights) in Azure to test the availability of my Mobile App Service. I ping the URL of the app service and check for a `200` HTTP response. If I receive 200 response, I decide that the test has passed. However, recently I noticed that the URL was giving me a 200 response, but the site gave me a message saying 'Critical service is unhealthy'.

This was a problem for me because I thought 200 was synonymous with 'everything being OK'. I want to know whether the URL will always give a 200 response and it is only the text message appearing on the site which will say whether the app service is running fine, unhealthy or down. If not, what are the different cases in which the URL responds with 200 HTTP code?

**EDIT:**

I think I couldn't clearly communicate my need in the question. I will try to do that now. The fact that I need to go through the diagnostic logs to debug the issue with my mobile service is clear to me and I am not asking for help on that front.

I am using the URL Ping Test to test the outside-in availability of the mobile service (synthetic availability check). Now, I check for the HTTP response 200 and deduce that the mobile app service is available. Now, that I have discovered that 200 is sent even when the app service is unhealthy, I need to modify my test. How can I do that to ensure that my availability test fails in such scenarios?

Additionally, the following is the webpage of the app service URL when all is fine. This webpage gives a 200 HTTP response. 
[image]

Now, is there a place where all the different webpage display of the app service URLs and the corresponding HTTP response codes are compiled?

Comment: Please see what you have in the logs. You may do that using Kudu - http://webapp.scm.azurewebsites.net (note scm). There is the console and you can find LogFiles folder here. That issue may be because of different reasons (for example, errors in the connection string), but it does not mean that your service is not able to answer

Comment: @Alex.... I think I couldn't convey my exact thoughts. I have edited the question giving a clarification. Pls check

Comment: If you are getting a 200, that means your service is healthy, at least for that endpoint. If other endpoints are the ones returning errors, then you need to add a ping test for those endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

A "URL Ping Test" is more than just a test for 200 - it will also (optionally) try to download all the images and files, do content matching, and retry if a failure is encountered.

Firstly, make sure you have a home page.  The home page can be turned off - that is dependent on your site.  Also, as @Alex suggested, turn on diagnostic logs and see what the error is produced.  Use Postman to send a request to the home page and see what you get back.

Comment: I think I couldn't convey my exact thoughts. I have edited the question giving a clarification. Pls check

Comment: If you have a mobile table that is "unhealthy" but is unauthenticated, then you can do a url ping of https://yoursite.azurewebsites.net/tables/yourtable

Answer (score 1):

Now, got the idea, i think. For being able to do what you want, i would offer you to customize a little your URL web test as described [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-monitor-web-app-availability/). If your web app returns 200 OK, and you suspect that there is something wrong, use the payload of the response. For example, if the payload of the response is not equal to "everything is OK", even if that is 200 OK the test should fail. I think that for now it is the only one way to implement that using URL tests from Appinsights.